# Trying to access the id field of a jsonwebtoken after logging in as the user but can't

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, jwt, backend

On the backend of my app, I am trying to save the id field of a jsonwebtoken to an item I created after logging in as a user. I am currently able to console log the info of the JWT but for some reason it won't let me assign the id field to my item.

```
//API endpoint for posting items
app.post("/postItem", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const { token } = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err: Error, info: Response) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(info);
    const newItem = new Item({
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price,
      category: req.body.category,
    });
    try {
      const createdItem = await newItem.save();
      res.json(createdItem);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).json(e);
    }
  });
});
```

I tried doing info.id but its saying id does not exist even though I am able to console log the id

```
//console.log(info) prints out { username: '1', id: '6599df386a8a03974c315e01', iat: 1704845251 } in my terminal
const newItem = new Item({
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price,
      category: req.body.category,
      author: info.id,                 //where the error is
    });
```

Comment: `info["id"]` probably?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I just tried that, but it didn't work. It gave me this error (error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>' has no index signature)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with optional chaining like info?.id,  also you can remove the verify function 3rd parameter empty object.

Comment: Unfortunately info?.id didn't work either but thank you for the other feedback!